Hbase Regions are in State OFFLINE and are Unassignable
We were configuring for hbase multiple nics and set both hbase.regionserver.ipc.address and hbase.master.ipc.address to 0.0.0.0. This caused hostname lookup issues which was a known issue years ago (we now know).
We've backed this out but ended up with 70 regions in a state of OFFLINE and still assigned to a Dead Region Servers with hostname 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
Restarting the master should transition this but it doesn't like the region name. Seems to want to split it during the transition:
2024-04-24 11:02:26,475 ERROR [MASTER_SERVER_OPERATIONS-master:60000-1] executor.EventHandler: Caught throwable while processing event M_SERVER_SHUTDOWN

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: **0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,60020,1713708572030-splitting**
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.suffix(Path.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.getLogDirs(MasterFileSystem.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitLog(MasterFileSystem.java:405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitLog(MasterFileSystem.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.splitLog(MasterFileSystem.java:281)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.handler.ServerShutdownHandler.process(ServerShutdownHandler.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.EventHandler.run(EventHandler.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,60020,1713708572030-splitting
    at java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:203)

I can verify that hadoop does not like the name:
/home/gs/Dev/hadoop/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir /hbase/WALs_mike/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,60020,1713708572030-splitting

Returns: /hbase/WALs_mike/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,60020,1713708572030-splitting is not a valid DFS filename
It's an older version:0.96.1.1
I think the main problem is the code can't handle the bad host name: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0.
Anyway to disable the splitting during M_SERVER_SHUTDOWN?
Anyway to rename the host associated with those regions?
Had no luck with hbck and shell assign, move, unassign:
2024-04-24 08:15:19,492 INFO  [RpcServer.handler=20,port=60000] master.AssignmentManager: Skip assigning c,\x92I$\x92I$\x92I$\x92I$\x92I$\x90,1330810355551.d31a033cd7810e347639e12833969754., it's host 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,60020,1713708572030 is dead but not processed yet


We have resolved this by:

Getting the hbase code and editing ServerShutdownHandler.java to skip splitting for server names starting with "0:0:0:0" and ignoring "Skip assigning region in transition on other server" logic.
We then swapped in the newly built hbase-server-096.1.12.jar and restarted the master. The master then reassigned all of the offline servers.

The hardest part was building the old hbase code with java6. Some of the maven dependencies needed changing or removing for our selected maven profiles.
